# What distro of Linux would work best on a Dell Vostro 200?

Tags: linux, hardware

I recently acquired an old computer (Dell Vostro 200) from my friend and want to see if I can make it run well in 2018. I figured Linux would be the best bet since it’s older hardware.
These are the specs:

- intel Pentium E2140 @ 1.6 ghz
- 4 Gb ram
- Nvidia GT (forgot number)

Curious if this is too old now or not, but I’d like to see what I can make happen.

Comment: Definitely not too old. My laptop has the same specs (minus Nvidia) and I could run all of the latest Linux releases. It has ran Slackware, Arch Linux, Debian, and most recently OpenBSD.

Comment: You could try LXLE http://www.lxle.net/

It's based on LUbuntu

Comment: try Linux Mint .... https://linuxmint.com/

Answer (score 1):

Asking what the best distro is is like asking what the best ice cream flavor is: nobody will agree. Ultimately the best distro is the one that suits you. With old machines like that, the software that you run on the distro will matter more than the distro itself. To run Linux fast on old machines, you should install a lightweight desktop like XFCE or LXQt, regardless of what distribution you choose.

I like Arch, but due to that being a bit difficult to set up, I would recommend Fedora here. However, this issue comes down mostly to preference, so you may want something else.